# nsf archiving format

Tags: email, lotus-notes, archiving

Does anyone know if nsf has an "ost" type equivilant? That is of course assuming that an nsf is equivilant to a pst. I am unfamiliar with Lotus notes and do not have a licensed version to test this on.

Comment: An NSF is much more versatile than a PST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Lotus Notes/Domino databases are .nsf files.

If you create an archive using the archive feature in a mail database, the archive is also a Lotus Notes database (and thereby also a .nsf file).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such an equivalent to a Outlook Offline Folder File. Lotus Notes can create database replicas on any supported device, including user's PC. File size of a replica file is limited by filesystem.